# Rails terminal commands run after 12 seconds why?

Tags: performance, powershell, windows-10, rake, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using ruby since 2 months i did small projects with express.js and django before.
My question is:

```
$ rails generate migration ...
$ rake db:migrate ...
$ rails console...
```

Why theese commands run after ~~12 seconds.?
I am using sqlite3. Rails 6.0.0

**My rails settings:**

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.2 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
```

On the other hand ruby, python, node shell, django dev server and express.js server commands running super fast.
Am i doing something wrong?

But i don't understand why making just one migration file command waits ~12 seconds to run?

**Example:** 
**This command runs after waiting 12 secs. I am using powershell and windows terminal**.

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ruby\xxxxxx\xxxxx> rails db:rollback
== 20200421123726 AddPartyIdToElections: reverting ============================
-- remove_column(:elections, :party_id, :int, {:before=>:created_at})
   -> 0.0630s
== 20200421123726 AddPartyIdToElections: reverted (0.0713s) ===================
```

- os windows 10
- Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
- 8 gb ram
- toshiba 250 gb ssd

This slowness reduce my learning curve. I want to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems this stiuation normal on windows machines. I tried linux mint it is faster than windows. 
Also there is a gem for fastering commands speed.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/412-fast-rails-commands